# Which tag should be kept as the main tag for the Google service for local business?

Tags: discussion, tags

As there are less than 10 questions this could not be a big issue but could be helpful to document this case.

There are three tags which names belongs to the name of a Google service at some point in the time but it's the same service. The current name of this service is Google My Business.

- [google-local](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-local) 2 questions no tag excerpt nor tag wiki.
- [google-places](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-places) 5 questions. It has a tag excerpt and tag wiki. The resources links now are redirected to Google My Business web content.
- [google-my-business](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-my-business) 3 questions. It has a tag excerpt and tag wiki but doesn't include resource links.

I think that the question with [google-local](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-local) and [google-places](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-places) should be retagged with [google-my-business](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-my-business) but perhaps it's better to make the first two a synonym of the last one. What do you think?

Comment: This seems reasonable to me. Although `local.google.com` redirects to `maps.google.com`, but the questions obviously are for this service.

Comment: Who knows what is the head of the Googlers :p . Being serious, I think that the people behind Google My Business are like business owners advocates rather than engineers with mission of making that the Google services be more helpful for them and their clients. I would like to think that this role inspired some of the scenes of "The Intership (the movie)" :D.

Comment: Synonym makes sense, didn't know it wasn't Places anymore

Comment: In the meantime I proposed edits to the three tags.

Comment: Please make sure you're putting usage guidance in the tag snippet. Don't describe the topic, but why the tag should (or should not) be used on a question. Leave the description of the topic, if necessary, to the tag wiki.

Comment: @AI E. see my "answer".

Answer (score 1):

Below are the edits proposed for the tags mentioned in the question.

[google-my-business](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-my-business)

In this case only the tag excerpt was edited to add "formerly named Google Local and later Google Places,"

[image: google-my-business]

[google-local](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-local)

[image: google-local]

[google-places](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-places)

[image: google-places]